# Adding elements in SOAP Header request w/o prefix

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soapheader

Below is how my SOAP header looks like. I was trying to add elements in the SOAP header and it throws me this error:

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: HeaderElements must be namespace qualified

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
        <a2z xmlns="http://test/sample">
         <UserName>test</UserName>
         <Password>abc</Password>
        </a2z>
        </soap:Header>
```

Here is the java code I'm working on to generate the soap request and it throws me error at this level:
e:

```
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
QName confirmation = new QName("a2z");
SOAPHeaderElement confirmationHeader = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(confirmation);
```

So how to add a header element like < a2z > which doesn't have any prefix.